# save or write the files of directory in sandbox file system to user selected directory in chrome app

Tags: google-chrome-app

Summary:

Is there any way to save all files of sandbox file system directory to user local directory? I need user prompt only for directory not for each files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible if you declare `"directory"` sub-permission in your manifest:

```
"permissions": [
  {"fileSystem": ["write", "directory"]}
]
```

Then, you can request access to a directory with [`chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-chooseEntry) using `type: "directory"`, <del>convert the result to a writable entry using [`chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-getWritableEntry)</del> (see comments) and then write the files you need.

Comment: It's not necessary to convert the DirectoryEntry to a writable one. I think that is a leftover from a previous implementation of these APIs. Permission "retainEntries" is needed only if the DirectoryEntry is to saved to reuse in a subsequent launch without having to again prompt the user. The retained entry can be saved in local storage.

Comment: Marc is correct, getWriteableEntry is a hangover and isn't needed.

Comment: @BenWells Updated the answer. I haven't actually ever written a Chrome App, so documentation is my main source of knowledge.